# How to open a partial view based on the image click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am writing you because I am bit lost.

I would like to create a page where there are 3 images, and each image is clickable.

When I click on one of the images, on the same page it should appear a partial view.

If I click another image, the all other partial views should disappear, and show only the partial view desired.

I have learned that in order to call a partial view the command line should be:

`@{
   Html.RenderPartial("_Android");
}`

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<h2>MDMSection</h2>
<p>The .thumbnail class can be used to display an image gallery.</p>
<p>The .caption class adds proper padding and a dark grey color to text inside thumbnails.</p>
<p>Click on the images to see all Q&A</p>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <img id="imgReloader" alt="Bootstrap Image Preview" src="http://lorempixel.com/140/140/" class="img-rounded" />
        <div class="caption">
            <p>Android</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <img id="image2" alt="Bootstrap Image Preview" src="http://lorempixel.com/140/140/" class="img-rounded" />
        <div class="caption">
            <p>iOS</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <img id="image3" alt="Bootstrap Image Preview" src="http://lorempixel.com/140/140/" class="img-rounded" />
        <div class="caption">
            <p>Windows Phone</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

my partial via should appear here...

Comment: you need to trigger a request to the server to render the relevant partial view. You can do it either with a full postback (passing some parameter which indicates to the server which view it should render when re-rendering the entire view), or probably better, trigger an ajax request to specifically download the partial's HTML and insert it into the right place in your page. Pretty sure you can get examples of that online already. You just need to trigger it from a JS "click" event handler attached to your images.

Comment: Actually what I have tried to do is this:

`<div id="output">
    
</div>`
`<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function ($) {
        $('#imgReloader').click(function () {
            $.get('@Url.Action("_AndroidView","PartialView")', {}, function (response) {
                $("#output").html(response);
        });
    });
</script>`

Comment: And what was the result? It looks more or less right at a glance. It'll only work for one of your image tags though. P.S. Please put that code into the question, it's not very clear or readable when placed in the comments.

Comment: The problem is that when I execute my website, and try click the image, nothing happens. No error message.
I check on _Layout.cshtml the refences fo jquery `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")`

and is correct. I even update on nuget package.

Yes indeed, I am trying to test with one image only.

I tested also to clal my partial view without script:
`@Html.Partial("~/Views/PartialView/_AndroidView.cshtml")`

and it works fine.

So I am stuck on my jquery script.

Comment: Did you debug in your browser tools? Check whether the event was fired, check whether the ajax call took place, and what response / error was received, if any. I can't debug that for you. Like I said, the code _looks_ right on the surface, but clearly something is not right. Only you can check what happens when the code actually runs. And you still didn't move your sample code into the question - please use the Edit feature to do that, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add **"onClick"** to your img tags that calls a function 
Like this:

```
<h2>MDMSection</h2>
<p>The .thumbnail class can be used to display an image gallery.</p>
<p>The .caption class adds proper padding and a dark grey color to text 
inside thumbnails.</p>
<p>Click on the images to see all Q&A</p>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <img id="imgReloader" alt="Bootstrap Image Preview" src="http://lorempixel.com/140/140/" class="img-rounded" onclick="ShowPartial('imgReloader')" />
    <div class="caption">
        <p>Android</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <img id="image2" alt="Bootstrap Image Preview" src="http://lorempixel.com/140/140/" class="img-rounded" onclick="ShowPartial('image2')" />
    <div class="caption">
        <p>iOS</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <img id="image3" alt="Bootstrap Image Preview" src="http://lorempixel.com/140/140/" class="img-rounded" onclick="ShowPartial('image3')" />
    <div class="caption">
        <p>Windows Phone</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

you need to add **three** division tag to your code too.
  use proper id for each division tag that can be created dynamically
for example "your Image's ID" + "DIV"

```
<div id="imgReloaderDiv" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 IMGDIV " style="display: none;"> </div>
<div id="image2Div" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 IMGDIV  " style="display: none;"> </div>
<div id="image3Div" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 IMGDIV  " style="display: none;"> </div>
```

**"ShowPartial()"** function should be like this:

```
<script>
function ShowPartial(ImgID) {
    $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: "Get",
            contentType: 'application/json',
            url: "@Url.Action("GetPartial", "your controller")",
          // send your data
            data: { firstData: "FirstValue", secondData: "SecondValue" },
            success: function (data) {
                $(".IMGDIV").slideUp();
                $("#" + ImgID + "Div").html(data);
                $("#" + ImgID + "Div").slideDown("slow");
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError, data) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }

        });

}
</script>
```

in your controller:

```
public ActionResult GetPartial(string firstData, string secondData)
    {
       //write needed codes
        return PartialView("_Android", model);
    }
```

Comment: Hello Mohaddes Sokhangou,
thank you very much for your help :)